# Squaring a binominal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, square-numbers

I have a really simple question that I can't find the answer to.
In a algebra test, I was asked to simplify $(5 + $$\sqrt{3}$)$^2$. What I did was to square each term individually:

$5^2$+$\sqrt{3}$$^2$

I got

$25 + 3$ = $28$

This however was the wrong answer. Was there a problem with squaring the binominal? 
Thanks!

Ps, This was their answer:

$28+10\sqrt{3}$

Comment: $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. You forgot the middle term !. It would then be $2 \times 5 \times \sqrt 3 = 10\sqrt 3$

Comment: The question has been answered already but you could've perhaps suspected an error as $\sqrt {3} >1$ This means $(5+ sqrt {3})^2>6^2=36$. Aways good to do a sanity check in exams. Hope it helps.

Comment: Another "sanity check" would be to put a rational number in place of the irrational number (square root in this case). If you were asked to simplify $(1+2)^2$ you would get $3^2=9$. However if you attempted to square each term individually and then add you would get $1^2+2^2=1+4=5$ which is obviously not the same as $9$ which you know is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(5+\sqrt{3})^2=(5+\sqrt{3})(5+\sqrt{3})$ then FOIL.

Comment: Duh. Thanks guys. I was thinking that I had to square them individually.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

You forget the term $2ab=2\times 5\times \sqrt{3}=10\times \sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$
where $a=5$ and $b=\sqrt {3}$